# Images are not fading in order in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am basically trying to have a the background change like a normal slideshow, however as you can see by the code below the first case has the images change abruptly and in the second case even though the images are changing smoothly the timing is either too short or too long and the fadeOut() tends to remain for the major part of the time making the background look white for most part of the time.
If anyone could help me by suggesting another way to place the different methods or anything please do.
Thank you!

```
setInterval(function () {
        $(".dexs").css("background-image", slides[c]);  
        $(".dexs").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".dexs").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".dexs").css("background-size", "cover");
        if (c == 1) 
            c = 0;

        else
            c = 1;

            console.log(c);


        }, 2000);
```

I have also tried keeping it in this manner -->

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var c = 0;
    var slides = ["url(bg.jpg)", "url(bg2.jpg)"];

    setInterval(function () {

        $(".dexs").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".dexs").css("background-size", "cover");
        $(".dexs").css("background-image", slides[c]);
        $(".dexs").fadeOut(1000);
        if (c == 1) 
            c = 0;

        else
            c = 1;

            console.log(c);


        }, 2000);


});
```

HTML -->
        `<img class="dexs"/>`
CSS -->

```
  '.dexs{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   height: inherit;
   width: inherit;
   background-size: cover;
   background-image: url(bg.jpg);
  }'
```

Comment: I believe when you have `$(".dexs").fadeOut(1000);` followed by `$(".dexs").fadeIn(1000);`your basically just having a fadeIn, as the code won't wait for the fadeOut to finish. Try having `setInterval(function () { $(".dexs").fadeOut(1000);}, 1000); $(".dexs").fadeIn(1000);`  , maybe?

Comment: If you are saying to keep the ' $(".dexs").fadeIn(1000); '  outside the 'setInterval' then it's not working because it'll just ' fadeOut() ' and repeat itself  not executing the ' fadeIn() ' function.